# Numba: Specifically excluding method from being optimized in a jitclass

Tags: python, class, methods, jit, numba

I am new to the whole topic about optimizing Python code and just started using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). The issue I currently face is that in some of my methods I compute FFTs with the help of [pyFFTW](https://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). From what I read it is not compatible with Numba. I am wondering what the best way to go about it would be. Here is a code snippet of the classes:

```py
class STFT:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def __call__(self, data):
        ...
        return stft

@jitclass
class PostProcessing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fft_object = pyfftw.FFTW()
        self.stft_object = STFT()
        ...

    def __call__(self, data):
        for x in range(self.num_samples):
            # Some Numpy operations.
            ...
            # Not Numba compatible FFT computation.
            fft_data = self.fft_object(data)
            # Some more Numpy operations.
            ...
            # Not Numba compatible STFT computation.
            stft_data = self.stft_object(processed_fft_data)
            # Some more Numpy operations.
            ...
```

**Question 1**: What would happen if I just left it as is. Would Numba still optimize all the `__call__`'s Numpy operations and just leave out the FFT and STFT computations? Or would it not optimize the method at all (or just with Numba's `object` mode)?

My initial idea was to put the FFT and STFT computations into their own methods. The `PostProcessing` class would then look something like below (`__init__` stays unchanged).

**Question 2**: Is there a Numba decorator to specifically exclude a method from optimization? Something like `@excludejit`? Or would I have to move the respective methods outside the `PostProcessing` class and pass everything it needs as arguments? I would love to avoid the latter though as it would defete the purpose of classes all together. Or is there an entirely different solution to achieve the same?

```py
@jitclass
class PostProcessing:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    @excludejit
    def compute_fft(self, data):
        return self.fft_object(data)

    @excludejit
    def compute_stft(self, data):
        return self.stft_object(data)

    def __call__(self, data):
        for x in range(self.num_samples):
            # Some Numpy operations.
            ...
            # Call method to compute FFT.
            fft_data = compute_fft(data)
            # Some more Numpy operations.
            ...
            # Call mehtod to compute STFT.
            stft_data = self.stft_object(processed_fft_data)
            # Some more Numpy operations.
            ...
```

Note: Eventually the `STFT` class is going to be a `@jitclass` as well. It is similar to the `PostProcessing` class. I just wanted to know the best way to go about it before I spend time rewriting it (and possibly having to do it all over again since I did not do it right the first time).

Your help is much appreciated!